# Crawl website with scrapy within application

Tags: python, scrapy

I am developing an application to crawl websites using Scrapy .I had a problem I want run the `scrapy crawl website` command within the application. Because the crawler will run from the browser.

Any Ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call a command from within your Python code. See here how that's done:
[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/1797792)

Comment: And, did it work? Then please mark this as an answer :)

Comment: Though I agree with @user1797792 and have done some similar things, just wanted to know what web framework you are using? I like Flask, but that means that you want to do stuff from the ground up, while Django has tons of apps, like this one [Django dynamic scraper](https://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and probably more.

Comment: I use Django . But i use scrappy for scrapping